# Release environment variables values not getting fetched in TFS Powershell script

Tags: powershell, variables, tfs

I am trying to use the release variables of TFS RELEASE_ENVIRONMENTID and RELEASE_RELEASEID to get the values so that i can check if all the steps are successful in the release CD. If any step fails then just rollback the changes:

```
Param([string] $BackupFolderName,[string] $TargetFolderName,[string] $releaseid,[string] $envid)

$releasequeryuri = "http://example.net:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/82d987654cfd-01ea-46c0-81d1-b2c98768508663/_apis/Release/releases/$(releaseid)/environments/$(envid)/tasks?api-version=3.0-preview.1"
$releasequeryresult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $releasequeryuri -Method Get -ContentType "application/json"  -UseDefaultCredentials      

foreach ($i in $releasequeryresult.value)
{
  if ($i.status -eq "failed")
  {

     Get-ChildItem -Path $(BackupFolderName) | Copy-Item -Destination $(TargetFolderName) -Force -Recurse
Write-Host "Copy complete"

   }
   else
   {
   Write-Host "Nothing to copy"
   }

 }
```

and the variables in the configure variable section is as below:

[image]

But it does not fetch the values of the variables. I definitely get those values when the initialize job step of release pipeline.Any help would be appreciated.

I have also tried putting the variables values as only RELEASE_RELEASEID and RELEASE_ENVIRONMENTID as but the values dont get fetched.

Comment: You can use the release variables directly as Shayki mention in below answer. : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#release-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the release environment variables on your PowerShell you don't need to create new variables, you can simply use the TFS variables in the script:

```
$envId= $env:RELEASE_RELEASEID
$releasequeryuri = "http://example.net:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/82d987654cfd-01ea-46c0-81d1-b2c98768508663/_apis/Release/releases/$(releaseid)/environments/$(envId)/tasks?api-version=3.0-preview.1"
```